# Way to get click event to work a single time with CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, iframe, hyperlink, click

I'm trying to have an iFrame appear and be able to be interacted with on a page after clicking a link on the same page.

Right now here is the page in question: http://informedinspectiontwo.com/authorization/

At the bottom, there is a link that says "I Have Read and Agree to the Terms and Conditions of This Authorization." Upon clicking this link, an iFrame appears right below it.

I want the iFrame to be able to be interacted with once it's available. As of right now, every time I click into the area of the iFrame, the frame closes (and then when the link is clicked again, it reopens ad infinitum). I am not sure exactly what I can do to make it stay around once the link's been clicked.

Instead of the iFrame closing when it is clicked, I need it to stay open so I can interact with it. So I need the click event to work only one time when clicking the link in question that opens the iFrame.

Here is my code, as it stands - **HTML within the page**:

```
<center>
<a href="https://app.acuityscheduling.com/schedule.php?owner=12005696#" target="frame" class="click_iframe" style="font-family:mongolian;" rel="noopener noreferrer"><font size="5px">I Have Read and Agree to the Terms and Conditions of This Authorization</font></a>
<div class="frame_div"><iframe name="frame" src="https://app.acuityscheduling.com/schedule.php?owner=12005696#" width="800" height="1000"></iframe></div></center>
```

**CSS:**

```
.frame_div{
    width: 800px;
    height: 1000px;
    display:none;
}
.frame_div iframe{
    height: 1000px;
    width: 800px;
}

.click_iframe{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.click_iframe:focus + div{
    display:block;
}
```

Any and all help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Can you use javascript here?

Comment: I think I need to download a plugin to use JS (since I'm using Wordpress with this site), but I believe it is indeed possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use javascript and write the html part you can add this script there it will be like

```
<center>
<a href="https://app.acuityscheduling.com/schedule.php?owner=12005696#" target="frame" class="click_iframe" style="font-family:mongolian;" rel="noopener noreferrer"><font size="5px">I Have Read and Agree to the Terms and Conditions of This Authorization</font></a>
<div class="frame_div"><iframe name="frame" src="https://app.acuityscheduling.com/schedule.php?owner=12005696#" width="800" height="1000"></iframe></div></center>
<script>
document.querySelector('.click_iframe').onclick=
function(){
  let frame = document.querySelector('.frame_div');
  if(frame.style.display==='block'){
    frame.style.display = 'none';
  }else{
    frame.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. You're saving me out here haha. Happy holidays!